# Is there a way to change GridControl Column header through coding?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, devexpress

I'm using a DevEx GridControl and I've two set of data to load in the same Grid(say on Button1_click first data should be loaded and on Button2_click next data should be loaded). Also the column headers should be changed correspondingly. Here i don't want to take two GridControls and set their visibility.
Thank you

Comment: Do you mean column header?

Comment: @luliia yes column header.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set AutoGenerateColumns to true and change the DataSource on button_click.

Comment: I'm afraid the [GridControl.AutoGenerateColumns](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfGridDataControlBase_AutoGenerateColumnstopic) property a bit more complex than plain boolean property))

Comment: myGrid.AutoGenerateColumns = AutoGenerateColumnsMode.RemoveOld should work.

Comment: Yes, of course, but it does not equals to "set property to true" approach from your answer

Comment: Thank you Riccardo. Is there a way to hide some columns from this data source because i don't want to populate all columns.

Comment: you can see the DmitryG's reply at step 3

Answer (score 0):

There are three common approaches for accomplishing this task:

1) Set the [GridControl.AutoGenerateColumns](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfGridDataControlBase_AutoGenerateColumnstopic) property to `AutoGenerateColumnsMode.RemoveOld` before assigning new data source. in this mode the grid creates columns for all fields in a new datasource, removing columns the grid already contains.

2) To create columns for all fields in a data source, call the [GridControl.PopulateColumns](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfGridDataControlBase_PopulateColumnstopic) method. This method clears the grid's [GridControl.Columns](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfGridGridControl_Columnstopic) collection, and re-populates it with columns/card fields that correspond to all fields in a data source.

3) Manage the grid's [GridControl.Columns](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfGridGridControl_Columnstopic) collection manually (to remove all unneeded and/or add/change all needed columns)

Answer (score -1):

You need [GridColumn.FieldName Property](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraGridColumnsGridColumn_FieldNametopic).

```
((GridView)gridControl.MainView).Columns[0].FieldName = "Your string";
```

Comment: @luliia: I'm afraid the approach you mentioned is not applicable for WPF DXGrid AS IS (OP talks about the DXGrid rather than XtraGrid)